# text-overflow ellipsis dots not showing in IE & Edge browsers if we have br tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

I am trying to apply text-overflow: ellipsis which includes a br tag in the specific div. In the chrome it is working fine and in IE & Edge browser ellipsis dots (...) not displaying. The 
 tags will be dynamically added.
[Please see the issue screenshot in EDGE & IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7kj5.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 


div.b {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 150px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b"> <b>Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!</b> <br /> second line text: Helloworld!Helloworld!Hello world!Hello world!</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont we change a structure a bit and it will work in IE too

```css
div.b{
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
div.b b, div.b p {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  display:block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b"> 
  <b>
    Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!Hello world!
  </b> 
  <p>
    second line text: Helloworld!Helloworld!Hello world!Hello world!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For other people's information:
I have this weird situation that the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` **not working on Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**.

**Details**: If I toggle the property `text-overflow` in developer tools, the text will rerender and truncate correctly, if I switch to another page then switch back, the text's truncation will not work.

**Solution**: After I examine the css styles on the element, I find the `display: block` under `:before:after` causes the problem, **remove** it then the truncation will behave as expected again.